# Why network model average could improve performance on test set?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

As people train a few network models and then do model average to improve the performance the final network. Then I'd like to know why model average could work? is there any paper or explanation on this?

Actually Dropout is also model average, then why dropout could works?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not a programming question.

Comment: This is a *huge* topic, and it's not confined to neural nets (i.e. it holds for ML in general); start by googling "model ensembles" and from the WIkipedia entry on [ensemble learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning)...

Answer (score 1):

People take model average so that if any of the models overfit the data, the combined model average will be able to provide a much more general prediction.